# Skype for Business IVR Bot

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I'd like to create a full sip capable IVR bot hooked to our Cloud PBX in Skype for Business.

It appears that this is possible with regular Skype but I can't find anything on how to do this with Skype for Business.

Is this possible? If so, how? any examples?

Also will this allow handling of multiple calls at the same time?

And is it possible to do outbound calling?